# Dual-boot Ubuntu sometimes boots to a black screen

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, windows-10, grub-efi, initramfs

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside Windows 10. Sometimes when I restart the laptop and select Ubuntu from Grub menu, I reach a black screen and then nothing happens. When I long press the power button to turn off the machine and restart it, it works.

On the next reboot, I get the `initramfs unpacking failed` message but the laptop boots to normal.

How do I debug what is going on?

Machine:

Lenovo P52 with Nvidia graphics. Runnining `nvidia-detector` gives me `nvidia-driver-440`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *seems* to be an issue with `initramfs`. Changing the compressing from `lz4` to `gzip` did the trick and I haven't booted to a black screen since I posted this question.